# How to find more than one matching pattern using Normalized Correalation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, correlation, normalize

I'm using normxcorr2 to find the area that exactly match with my pattern and i also want to find the other area(in the red rectangle) that is look like the pattern. I think it will be works if i can find the next maximum and so on and that value must not in the first maximum area or the first one that it has been detected but i can't do it. Or if you have any idea that using normxcorr2 to find the others area please advise me, I don't have any idea at all.
Here's my code. I modified from this one http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/image/cross_correlation/imreg.html

```
onion = imread('pattern103.jpg'); %pattern image
peppers = imread('rsz_1jib-159.jpg'); %Original image

onion = rgb2gray(onion);
peppers = rgb2gray(peppers);

%imshow(onion)
%figure, imshow(peppers)

c = normxcorr2(onion,peppers);
figure, surf(c), shading flat

% offset found by correlation
[max_c, imax] = max(abs(c(:)));
[ypeak, xpeak] = ind2sub(size(c),imax(1));
corr_offset = [(xpeak-size(onion,2))
               (size(onion,1)-ypeak)]; %size of window show of max value 

offset = corr_offset;
xoffset = offset(1);
yoffset = offset(2);

xbegin = round(xoffset+1); fprintf(['xbegin = ',num2str(xbegin)]);fprintf('\n');
xend   = round(xoffset+ size(onion,2));fprintf(['xend = ',num2str(xbegin)]);fprintf('\n');
ybegin = round(yoffset+1);fprintf(['ybegin = ',num2str(ybegin)]);fprintf('\n');
yend   = round(yoffset+size(onion,1));fprintf(['yend = ',num2str(yend)]);fprintf('\n');

% extract region from peppers and compare to onion
extracted_onion = peppers(ybegin:yend,xbegin:xend,:);
if isequal(onion,extracted_onion)
   disp('pattern103.jpg was extracted from rsz_org103.jpg')
end

recovered_onion = uint8(zeros(size(peppers)));
recovered_onion(ybegin:yend,xbegin:xend,:) = onion;
figure, imshow(recovered_onion)

[m,n,p] = size(peppers);
mask = ones(m,n);
i = find(recovered_onion(:,:,1)==0);
mask(i) = .2; % try experimenting with different levels of
              % transparency

% overlay images with transparency
figure, imshow(peppers(:,:,1)) % show only red plane of peppers
hold on
h = imshow(recovered_onion); % overlay recovered_onion
set(h,'AlphaData',mask)
```

[image: Extracted Area]

[image: Output]

[image: Pattern]

[image: Originalimage]

Comment: The purpose of this work is to detect all the area inside the red line.

Comment: Could you please attach the figure obtained from `figure, surf(c), shading flat`? My guess is you just need to find local maxima in this image.

Comment: yes, i already find the maxima and that value is where the pattern matching with the original image.(Thw gray scal image is the output) and i want to find the second maima and so on but that maxima have not locate into the first one.